# radare2 search first occurrence before

Tags: radare2

Is it possible to use radare2 to perform a search like the following:

> **first occurence of `ldr r1` before address 0x000048b4**

[image]

In the following example it should return:

```
0x000048b2 ldr r1, [pc, 0x20]
```

radare2 is able to guess the value of `[pc, 0x20]` (511). Would it be possible to retrieve that separately ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can tell radare2 how much results do you want with the `search.count` variable, and you can also adjust your search window with the `search.from` and `search.to` ones.

Feel free to check `e??~search` (`e` for evaluate, `??` to get help about the configuration variables (`?` is used to get help about `e` itself), and `~` for the internal filtering, here, on *search*).

To search for opcodes, you can use `/a`, to *search* *a*ssembled opcodes.

The matching offset will automatically have a `hit0_0` flag attributed.

So, something like:

```
e search.count = 1
e search.to = 0x000048b4
/a ldr r1
pd 1 @ hit0_0
```